# href from another page using react-router

Tags: html, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I have a header menu in my web page, inside the menu I have sections and subsections, one of the subsections will jump me to the position where the section is in the home page

for this I am using react router hash

```
import { HashLink as Link } from 'react-router-hash-link';
<Link to="/#map-section">
Section of home page
</Link>
```

this works if I am in the current page where the section I want to jump is, but it doesnt work at all when I am in another page and I wanna go to the main page and then jumping to the section.
I am guessing that component where the section is has not finished loading when i am trying to get there. Is there any way to manage this?

Comment: Can you provide a more complete code example in your question? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. If possible, think you could also try creating a *running* codesandbox demo that reproduces the issue we could inspect and debug live?

Comment: I think something with your <Link to ="navigate"> are wrong, here is a very informative example to how use him https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Link I hope my answer guided you.

Answer (score 0):

Please check below codesandbox.
It worked.
https://codesandbox.io/s/zen-swartz-59rj4